# Part 2_Selenium Webdriver using java _How toccess & read the Microsoft Office Professional Plus AOutlook 2010 Emails using SMTP or iMAP

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Hello i have created following code to acces the outlook but facing exception in thread main  can someone guide me to identify whats wrong with following code
sample code`

public class Email_Reading {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable   {

    String host ="smtp-mail.outlook.com";
    String username = "ABQA_Test@outlook.com";
    String password = "Test@1234";
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.startls.enable", "true");
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
    MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
    Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");


    try

    {
        transport.connect(host, username, password);
        transport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());

    }

    finally{

        transport.close();

    }
    `
```

Error Details

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1082)

    at Email_Reading.main(Email_Reading.java:28)

Answer (score 0):

The below code is working for me. Only thing is make sure that the recipient's email address is not blocked:

```
final String username = "you outlook email address";
final String password = "you password";

Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp-mail.outlook.com");
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
Session session = Session.getInstance(props,new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
      protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
        }
      });

try {

     Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
     message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("you email address"));
     message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
     InternetAddress.parse("recipient email address"));
     message.setSubject("Subject line");
     message.setText("message body");

     Transport.send(message);
     System.out.println("Mail sent!");

} catch (MessagingException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package Utility;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.activation.*;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;



class SendAttachment{  
 private static final String Objet = "recent";

public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception, MessagingException{  

     Properties props = null;
        if (props == null) {
            props = new Properties();
            props.put("mail.smtp.auth", true);
            props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", true);
            props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp-mail.outlook.com");
            props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
            props.put("mail.smtp.user", "krishnajntu2009@outlook.com");
            props.put("mail.smtp.pwd", "varanane56");
        }
        Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
        session.setDebug(true);
        Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);

     msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("krishnajntu2009@outlook.com"));
        if (Objet != null) {
            msg.setSubject(Objet);

        }
      //3) create MimeBodyPart object and set your message text     
        BodyPart messageBodyPart1 = new MimeBodyPart();  
        messageBodyPart1.setText("This is message body");  

        //4) create new MimeBodyPart object and set DataHandler object to this object      
        MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart2 = new MimeBodyPart();  

        String filename = "/Users/krishnabadveli/Downloads/Resume (1).pdf";//change accordingly  
        DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);  
        messageBodyPart2.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));  
        messageBodyPart2.setFileName(filename);  


        //5) create Multipart object and add MimeBodyPart objects to this object      
        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();  
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart1);  
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart2);  

        //6) set the multiplart object to the message object  
        msg.setContent(multipart );  



        msg.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress("krishnajntu2009@outlook.com"));
        Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
        transport.connect("smtp.live.com", 587, "krishnajntu2009@outlook.com", "varanane56");
        transport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
        System.out.println("Mail sent successfully at " + "krishnajntu2009@outlook.com");
        transport.close();
 }
}
```